# Python - Space Complexity of Nonlocal Variables in HOF

Tags: python, recursion, memory, space-complexity

I was wondering if I were to reference a nonlocal variable in a HOF, how much extra memory would it cost me? For example:

```
def f():
    lst = [1, 2, ... , 100]
    def g():
        print(lst) # or anything that references lst
        g()
f()
```

I was thinking that if the recursion depth reaches something like 100 levels, how does `g` know where to find `lst`? How does Python work under the hood? If it is storing a pointer to `lst`, there should be extra memory cost right? Hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> how does `g` know where to find `lst`?

`g`'s scope includes read access to variables from the enclosing scope (it'd need `nonlocal` or `global` to be able to reassign as well). The presence of recursion has no impact on scoping here.

> If it is storing a pointer to `lst`, there should be extra memory cost right?

No, it's just following a reference to `lst` in the enclosing scope rather than copying `lst`'s contents to its local frame. At worst, the reference variable is a constant factor increase in the memory footprint of each frame which is irrelevant from a space complexity perspective.

The space complexity of calling this function looks like it might be `O(len(lst) + space_cost_of_g_frame * calls_to_g)`. But the `space_cost_of_g_frame` is constant, so it's dropped, and it's unclear what `calls_to_g` is (right now, it's 0, which is O(1), but that'd also apply if it was infinite or any hardcoded value). Finally, `lst` is a hardcoded length, also O(1). So the overall space cost of this function is O(1) as you've written it.

To get `n` involved in the complexity, you need a parameter of some sort. Since complexity analysis is only concerned with growth, if all the calls have the same cost regardless of the input, it's O(1) no matter how expensive that call might be.

> how much extra memory would it cost me?

That's implementation-dependent, but probably miniscule and nothing to worry about unless you actually run into a real problem, in which case, constant factor details that complexity analysis ignores start to matter greatly (use case/application goals, characteristics of the machine/environment, the exact function code rather than pseudocode, etc).